# how to change the name of JSONObject dynamically

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have few dialog's in which the user enters their details(person details- first name, last name etc..), I need to capture the details and convert to JSON. 
User can enter more than one person details like. person1, person2, person3(which should be the JSONObjects). When ever the bellow function is called for the first time I want 
JSONObject personJSON1 = new JSONObject();
second time its called 
JSONObject personJSON2 = new JSONObject(); and so on. 
Could you please suggest how can i achieve this.

```
private void personAdded() {
JSONObject personJSON = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray personArrayjson = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject personObjectJson = new JSONObject();
        try {           
                personObjectJson.put("otherFirstName", sOtherFirstName);
                personObjectJson.put("otherLastName", sOtherLastName);  
                personObjectJson.put("otherAddress", sOtherAddress);
                personObjectJson.put("otherTown", sOtherTown);  
                personObjectJson.put("otherCounty", sOtherCounty);
                personObjectJson.put("otherPostcode", sOtherPostcode);  
                personObjectJson.put("otherTelephone", sOtherTelephone);
                personObjectJson.put("otherMobilePhone", sOtherMobilePhone);    
                personObjectJson.put("otherEmail", sOtherEmail);
                personObjectJson.put("otherPersonInvolvement", sHowWasTheOtherPersonInvolved);          

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Your help/suggestions much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You could use a list of `JSONObject` and for each new person you add a new element to the list.

Comment: can you suggest any links or examples for list of JSONObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<JSONObject> mMyList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

    private void personAdded() {
        JSONObject personJSON = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray personArrayjson = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject personObjectJson = new JSONObject();
                try {           
                        personObjectJson.put("otherFirstName", sOtherFirstName);
                        personObjectJson.put("otherLastName", sOtherLastName);  
                        personObjectJson.put("otherAddress", sOtherAddress);
                        personObjectJson.put("otherTown", sOtherTown);  
                        personObjectJson.put("otherCounty", sOtherCounty);
                        personObjectJson.put("otherPostcode", sOtherPostcode);  
                        personObjectJson.put("otherTelephone", sOtherTelephone);
                        personObjectJson.put("otherMobilePhone", sOtherMobilePhone);    
                        personObjectJson.put("otherEmail", sOtherEmail);
                        personObjectJson.put("otherPersonInvolvement", sHowWasTheOtherPersonInvolved);          
       mMyList.add(personJSON)
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Doing the list implementation would look something like this.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what i was looking for. one question in this. User can delete a person, in this case how do I delete from the list for a perticular person lets say person1 needs to be deleted

Comment: API references are here to help you:  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html

Comment: To remove use `mMyList.remove()`, you can remove by position or by the JSONObject.